# How to navigate between screens with StackNavigator if I have different js files for each screen?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

fairly new to React Native. I have read the stack navigator docs and still don't get how to do this.

So I have a bottom tab navigator, and I want to implement a stack navigator in one of the tabs, so I can navigate from the main tab screen to the second screen, but from the second screen to third screen I cannot navigate as it can't find the variable "navigation", which is understandable because I'm using different js files for each screen. How do I pass over the navigation variable to the other screen? Below is my code:

OrderScreen.js:

```
imports...

import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    }
});

function Orderscreen({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.welcome}>
            <View styles={styles.container}>
                <Button style={styles.button1} color="warning" uppercase onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('Scan QR code') }}><Text style={styles.buttonText}>Take me to screen SCAN QR CODE</Text></Button>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
};

import { Qrcodescanner } from './qrcodescanner';
import { Menu } from './menu';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

function MenuScreen({ navigation }) {
    return(
    <Menu></Menu>
    )
}

function QRScanScreen({ navigation }) {
    return(
        <Qrcodescanner></Qrcodescanner>
    )
}

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Orderscreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Scan QR code" component={QRScanScreen}
                options={{
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <Button shadowless
                            onlyIcon icon="question" iconFamily="antdesign" iconSize={30} color="info" iconColor="#fff" style={{ width: 35, height: 35, marginRight: 20 }}
                        />
                    ),
                }}
            />
            <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuScreen} />

        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Qrcodescanner.js:

```
export class Qrcodescanner extends React.Component {
  ...

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission, scanned } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <Text> Requesting for camera permission </Text>;
    }
    if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text> No access to camera </Text>;
    }
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          flexDirection: 'column',
          justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        }}> ...
      </View>
    );
      }
  handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data}) => {
    this.setState({
      scanned: true,
    });
    alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);

    navigation.navigate('Menu')
};

  };
```

So when I do scan something, it should navigate to the 'Menu' screen but instead I get the error: 'can't find variable: navigation'. How do I pass the navigation variable to a different js file?

Comment: you need to use, `this.props.navigation` insted of using  `navigatino` since its injected in the props of that component if its exists in the route mappings of `createStackNavigator`

Comment: Yes, well I still get an error, it can't find this.props.navigation as it is not declared in the Qrcodescanner screen js file, but in OrderScreen.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have seen your cod and got a solution for you you just have to create a new file `NavigationServices.js`

```
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator
};
```

and then import the file in your `.js` file and use it to navigate like in your `OrderScreen.js:`

```
import NavigationService from "../NavigationService";
```

and use it like this.

```
NavigationService.navigate("Qrcodescanner");
```